# bootstrap panel class captures the content of above div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I got 2 divs, one with `panel` bootstrap class, another without, and I need to place this `panel` div below the regular one. Now it looks like this:

[image: first_pic]

but when I place my `panel` div below regular one I get the following:

[image: 2nd pic]

so the upper content is capured by `panel` div. The code is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="form_container" style="float:left;">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group pull-left">
                    <input id="message" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Введите фразу и нажмите Enter" autofocus="" autocomplete="off">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-add" type="button" id="chat_send">Отправить</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="server" class="col-xs-2 control-label" style="padding-left: 14%;padding-right: 10%;margin-top: 5px;">Сервер</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <select class="form-control" id="server" name="server_field">
                        {% for server_addr in server_address %}
                        {% for k, v in server_addr %}
                            <option value="{{ v }}">{{ k }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top: 1%;" >
        <div class="panel-body" style="padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 0;">

            <div class="form-group col-md-8" style="margin-top:12px;">
                <label for="phrase_group" class="col-xs-3 control-label" style="margin-top: 5px;">Выберите группу</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <select class="form-control" id="phrase_group" name="phrase_group" style="width:40%; float:left;">
                        <option value="{{ group.id }}">{{ group.phraseset }}</option>
                        {% for group in group_phrases %}
                            <option value="{{ group.id }}">{{ group.phraseset }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                    <button id="test_phraseset" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 10%;" data-id="2">Тест</button>
                    <button id="clear_phraseset" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 7%;" data-id="2">Очистить</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas how to fix that? thank you.

Comment: Bootstrap push and pull

Comment: Could you please clarify, what does that mean?

Comment: first suggestion: remove all your inline styling. your floats and margins and padding etc.. is breaking BS styling.  Apply BS styling only at first, get it working, then apply custom styling as needed.  If you are using BS4 then prefer [BS4 Utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/borders/) over inline styling